# How to create fullscreen theme for ImageView in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-studio

I want to put an `ImageView` in my application and then set it to fullscreen.

I had tried following code in Android Studio.(and I also tried in Eclipse IDE)

My minimum required

> **SDK**            : API 8:Android 2.2 froyo,
>      **Target** SDK     :  API 19:Android 4.4 KitKat,
>      **Compile With**   :  API 19:Android 4.4 KitKat,
>      **Langauge Level** :6.0-ovrrride in interface,
>      **Theme**          :Holo Light With Dark Action Bar.

Then in activity_main.xml code is below:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.crystal.app.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ddd" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where I set theme as `Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`.

and I changed AndroidManifest.xml code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.crystal.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.crystal.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Then I run the Application in AVD but when I open Application it shows the error like:

> Unfortunately,(app name) has Stopped (and OK button)

So ,What is wrong with my code.

and also tell that in how many ways I can do this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: show your logcat error...

Comment: man show the logcat error.....

Comment: What you want to do.....Do you want to set splash screen???? can you give little bit more idea.... and also please post your logcat here...

Comment: AS i said above Unfortunately,has Stopped when i run application and no logcat error are found

Comment: You will not get that error without there being useful logcat entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned above my Minimum requires sdk is Android 2.2 froyo which not support

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

It is supported by only more then api level of 14(Icecream Sandwitch)
so my Minimum required sdk should be Android 4.0 or Android API level should greater or equal to 14.